# Eliminar linha de um arquivo em C

Tags: c

Estou a fazer um projeto de uma mercearia. Os produtos são guardados num ficheiro linha a linha assim: codigo(int)$nome(string)$quantidade(int)$preço(int)$.
Como posso fazer para eliminar um produto( ou seja, uma linha especifica)?

Comment: Que arquivo é esse?

Answer (score 3):

Muito interessante a pergunta! Pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    

#define ARQUIVO_ESCOLHIDO 1
#define LINHA_DO_ARQUIVO 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[ARQUIVO_ESCOLHIDO], "r"); //Arquivo de entrada.
    FILE *output = fopen("transferindo.txt", "w"); //Arquivo de saída.
    char texto[1001] = ""; //Uma string larga o suficiente para extrair o texto total de cada linha.
    unsigned int linha_selecionada = atoi(argv[LINHA_DO_ARQUIVO]);
    unsigned int linha_atual = 1;
    while(fgets(texto, 1001, input) != NULL){
        if(linha_atual != linha_selecionada){
            fputs(texto, output);
        }
        memset(texto, 0, sizeof(char) * 1001);
        linha_atual += 1;
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    remove(argv[ARQUIVO_ESCOLHIDO]);
    rename("transferindo.txt", argv[ARQUIVO_ESCOLHIDO]);
    return 0;
}
```

Basicamente, criamos dois ponteiros para arquivos, um de entrada e um de saída. O de entrada carregou o arquivo escolhido pelo usuário, que é o primeiro parâmetro que ele passou na linha de comando. O de saída criou um arquivo próprio, `transferindo.txt`, que vai simplesmente receber os dados que queremos que continuem na nossa lista.

Depois, criamos uma string de texto na stack (lembrando que ela precisa ter tamanho suficiente para receber dados para uma linha de texto do arquivo), e criamos dois inteiros positivos, um que converte o texto ASCII do segundo parâmetro da linha de comando em um inteiro que representa a linha que queremos remover, e o outro que contém a linha que estamos atualmente analisando.

No loop while, usamos `fgets` para obter os conteúdos de cada linha, até que `fgets` retorne NULL, ou seja, até que ele encontre o fim do arquivo. Aí vem a parte interessante: Se a linha cuja exclusão foi solicitada na linha de comando for a linha que estamos atualmente analisando, não fazemos nada. Do contrário, copiamos o conteúdo da linha para nosso arquivo de saída. Depois, limpamos a string na qual armazenamos a linha e aumentamos `linha_atual` em 1, o que significa que passamos para a próxima linha de texto do arquivo de entrada.

Acabado o loop while, fechamos os dois ponteiros para arquivos. Em seguida, usamos a função `remove` para deletar o arquivo que o usuário pediu que fosse modificado, para que possamos trocá-lo pela versão atualizada do arquivo, `transferindo.txt`. Então, usamos `rename` para renomear o arquivo `transferindo.txt`, dando a ele o nome do arquivo original.

Pronto! Agora temos um arquivo atualizado!

Lembrando que você não está limitado à função `main`. Esse exemplo é só uma das múltiplas formas de se implementar o que você quer! :)